# Convert NSString That Contains Sign Operation To NSURL

Tags: objective-c, url, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to convert `NSString` that contains sign operation to `NSURL`:

```
NSString *urls = @"https//graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+actor_id,created_time+from+straem+where+created_time+>+2661222&access_token";
NSURL *realurl = [NSURL URLWithString:urls];
```

**realurl return -->> nil**

The main problem is   `created_time+>+2661222`, actually   "**>**" sign operation.
 `NSURL` can't convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you probably want to use [NSString's "`stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`" method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding%3a).

In other words, something like:

```
NSString * urls = @"https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+actor_id,created_time+from+straem+where+created_time+>+2661222&access_token";
NSURL * realURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [urls stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the string first:

```
NSURL *realURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [urls stringByAddingPercentEscapeUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: +1 to you for thinking the same thought as me at the same time